# Do dogs comprehend that a three-legged dog is missing a leg?

Tags: dogs, psychology

I assume that other dogs identify the three-legged dog as being impaired in some way, but do they specifically realize that the dog has three legs when it should have four?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never seen any sign that the find this particularly odd. Then again, they have no trouble recognizing that everything from Chihuahua  to St. Bernard is a dog, so maybe a missing leg just isn't any odder.

I think it takes more time-binding than dogs can do to formulate the question "how did that happen", and without that different shape is just different. Might affect mate choice, but I'm not sure of that either if the injured dog is getting around well and in good health otherwise.